# converting xls in csv

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv

I am trying to import some `csv` file in `sql` format after extracting this `csv` file from `xls`. I put here the only first line

```
sortorder,code OccupLabel1_EN,code OccupLabel2_EN,code_20090606,OccupLabel1_EN,OccupLabel2_EN,OccupLabel3_EN source list_20090606,Country for sorting,IN TRANSL SHEET 1=yes,lvl 1 wit voor vertaling 1=yes,lvl 2 wit voor vertaling 1=yes,sortorder lvl2 voor anne 9=support services,sortorder lvl3 voor anne 9=all other, -,fr_FR_20090606,TRANSLATE & CHECK,TRANSLATE & CHECK,job description
#jump to line
1,-10000,-20004,2132010000000,"Agriculture, nature, animals, environment",Agriculture,Agricultural advisor,0,1,0,0,1,1, -,"Agriculture, nature, animaux, environnement",Agriculture,Conseiller agricole,
```

When I try to import it in my MAMP sql server, I get this message

```
Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.
```

It seems that the string `"Agriculture, nature, animals, environment"` is interpreted as 4 distinct columns wright ? So how to deal with that issue ?

Comment: Can't you use the `LOAD DATA` command to import the excel file directly?

Comment: @jbarker2160 sorry I don't know this command. How does it work ?

Comment: [MySQL 5.5 LOAD DATA Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)